# Why I can't dinamically replace the immage of an ImageView into this simple Android application?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview

I am doing the first experiment with Android and I have the following problem with this simple application.

Basically my application consist into an **ImageView** showing a background immage, a **TextView** showing a message and a button.

When the user click this button the text of my TextView have to change and the background immage of my ***ImageView** also have to change.

So this is my **activiy_main.xml** file containing the layout of my main activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B388FF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/android_cookie_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/before_cookie" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="I'm so hungry"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="34sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="EAT COOKIE"
        android:onClick="eatCookie"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code of the previous activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void eatCookie(View v) {

        TextView messaggio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
        messaggio.setText("I'm so full");

        ImageView sfondo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);
        sfondo.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/after_cookie"));

    }
}
```

As you can see, when the user click the button it is  perform the **eatCookie()** method that first retrieve the **TextView** reference and change the text of this **TextView**. It works fine.

Then it retrieve the reference related to the **ImageView** and try to change the viewed immage, I have done it by this line:

```
sfondo.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/after_cookie"));
```

In my project I have put the **after_cookie.jpg** file into the **/res/drawable/** folder.

The problem is that it can't work. The default immage of the **android_cookie_image_view** disappear but is not replaced with the **after_cookie.jpg** image.

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you called `eatCookie function` on `onCreate` method ?

Comment: Change the `setImageDrawable()` call to `setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie)`.

Comment: why on earth use [drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromPath(java.lang.String))  like this ( i'm not sure `@drawable/something` return String path/URI) ?  whats wrong with `setImageResource(R.drawable)` its easy and you don't convert anythong just pass `int` value to it.

Comment: if you want to draw your images dynamically then you need to use Adapter and in side adapter class you need to use handler for handle multiple images

Answer (score 0):

**Use this instead.**

```
 ImageView sfondo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);
 sfondo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.after_cookie));
```

> And make sure you call that `eatCookie` function on `onCreate`.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        eatCookie();
    }
```

Comment: @Hosseini He is using `AppCompatActivity` only not `Fragment`. No need to add that `View` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sfondo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.after_cookie));
```